# Last Day of Previous month based on cell date given in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Last Day of Previous month based on cell date given in excel , example used A1 cell as 6/23/2016 …. Have applied formula in b1 cell  '=EOMONTH(A1,-1) … output am getting in number format  could you please help to get date format here ? Any formula which helps apart from this ? Much appreciated with your responses

Comment: You need to format the cell to the date type you want.  The number is the number of days since 1/1/1900.

Comment: I agreed any other formula which helps me to get last day of previous month based on given cell date.

Comment: The best method would is to use the cell format.  In the home tab change to short date.  Otherwise you will end up with a text string that makes searches more difficult.  To get text use TEXT()" `=TEXT(EOMONTH(A1,-1),"mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: Thank you so much :-) for your quick response.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract the day-of-month from whatever date you have.

```
=a1-day(a1)
```

Excel *tries* to carry the primary formatting from the precedent cells in a formula but sometimes it cannot so it defaults to a general number. EOMONTH is often the latter; simple subtraction seems to work.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The format is applied as follows:

[image]